# React hooks async cleanup warning dance

Tags: reactjs

I've seen some similar questions but not one that is worded exactly like this:

I have an imperative API I am exposing via the declarative React component model, and for the most part it is going very well, but I have run into some warnings that I don't know how to address, so I have been ignoring.

I have a custom hook that looks roughly like this:

```
function useViewer(someDependency) {
  const [ready, setReady] = useState(true);
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!ready) return;
    const viewer = makeViewer(someDependency);
    return () => {
      setReady(false);
      viewer.cleanup().then(() => setReady(true));
    }
  }, [someDependency, ready]);
}
```

The point of this `ready` flag is that the viewer's cleanup needs to happen before a subsequent viewer is created.

When I do this, however, I get this warning:

> Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function.

I can make the state update not happen while the component is unmounted like this:

```
function useViewer(someDependency) {
  const [ready, setReady] = useState(true);
  const hasUnmountedRef = useHasUnmounted();
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!ready) return;
    const viewer = makeViewer(someDependency);
    return () => {
      setReady(false);
      viewer.cleanup().then(() => {
        const hasUnmounted = hasUnmountedRef.current;
        if (!hasUnmounted) setReady(true);
      });
    }
  }, [someDependency, ready]);
}


function useHasUnmounted() {
  const unmountedRef = useRef(false);
  useEffect(() => () => {
    unmountedRef.current = true;
  }, []);
  return unmountedRef;
}
```

But that makes there be a different warning from the eslint react-hooks/exhaustive-deps rule:

> The ref value 'hasUnmountedRef.current' will likely have changed by the time this effect cleanup function runs. If this ref points to a node rendered by React, copy 'hasUnmountedRef.current' to a variable inside the effect, and use that variable in the cleanup function. eslint (react-hooks/exhaustive-deps)

The problem w/ their suggestions is that I *want* to have the current value of the ref as of the cleanup phase, not the current value at the beginning of the effect.

I think this comes down to asynchronous cleanup - how can I asynchronously cleanup after an effect before a subsequent effect occurs?  A previous iteration *enqueued* the effects that I wanted, but that made cleanup very difficult.

Comment: I'm a little confused with your original example, `useEffect` cleanup function is called every time the dependency in deps is changed and you are basically resetting the ready to false and then clean up and then set to true.

it'd be really helpful if you could create a MVE with reproducible behavior with a broader context to understand what does this solve. It will also help to understand this specific nugget better to be able to understand how to help.